# ModelMapper mapping error message - Spring 5

Tags: java, spring

So when I make the following post request

```
{
    "firstName":"Theo",
    "lastName":"Tziomakas",
    "email":"email1@gmail.com",
    "password":"theo123",
    "addresses":[
        {
            "city":"Larissa",
            "country":"Greece",
            "streetName":"Epirou 5",
            "postalCode":"41223",
            "type":"shipping"
        },
        {
            "city":"Larissa",
            "country":"Greece",
            "streetName":"Iasonos 33",
            "postalCode":"41223",
            "type":"billing"
        }
    ]
},
```

I am getting this error.

```
<ErrorMessage>
    <timestamp>2019-03-20T14:41:02.313+0000</timestamp>
    <message>ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter@4eab446e failed to convert java.lang.String to long.
Caused by: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping pzyzcL3jRCSH4MR7Xxpdiyr3j8gC69 to java.lang.Long

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.toMappingException(Errors.java:258)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.numberFor(NumberConverter.java:181)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.convert(NumberConverter.java:75)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.convert(NumberConverter.java:57)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:368)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:253)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:135)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:101)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.IterableConverter.convert(IterableConverter.java:49)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:368)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:253)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:135)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:101)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:60)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:539)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:372)
    at theo.restful.webservices.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.createUser(UserServiceImpl.java:56)
    at theo.restful.webservices.ui.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at theo.restful.webservices.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationFilter.java:31)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "pzyzcL3jRCSH4MR7Xxpdiyr3j8gC69"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.numberFor(NumberConverter.java:171)
    ... 109 more

2) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter@4eab446e failed to convert java.lang.String to long.
Caused by: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping vXMpa0liPNslDH70y0pc4Z3XTpRhsJ to java.lang.Long

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.toMappingException(Errors.java:258)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.numberFor(NumberConverter.java:181)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.convert(NumberConverter.java:75)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.convert(NumberConverter.java:57)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:368)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:253)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:135)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:92)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.IterableConverter.convert(IterableConverter.java:49)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:368)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:253)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:135)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:101)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.IterableConverter.convert(IterableConverter.java:49)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.convert(MappingEngineImpl.java:368)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:96)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:253)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:187)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:135)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:101)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:60)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:539)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:372)
    at theo.restful.webservices.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.createUser(UserServiceImpl.java:56)
    at theo.restful.webservices.ui.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at theo.restful.webservices.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationFilter.java:31)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "vXMpa0liPNslDH70y0pc4Z3XTpRhsJ"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter.numberFor(NumberConverter.java:171)
    ... 116 more

2 errors</message>
</ErrorMessage>
```

I am using the ModelMapper class inside the createUser method of my controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}",
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE} )
    public UserRest getUser(@PathVariable String id){

        UserRest returnValue = new UserRest();

        UserDto userDto = userService.getUserByUserId(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDto, returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

    @PostMapping(
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public UserRest createUser(@RequestBody UsersDetailsRequestModel userDetails) throws Exception{


        //if(userDetails.getFirstName().isEmpty()) throw new NullPointerException("The object is null");

//        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
//        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails,userDto);


        // UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        // BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails, userDto);
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(userDetails, UserDto.class);

        UserDto createdUser = userService.createUser(userDto);
        UserRest returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdUser, UserRest.class);


        return returnValue;
    }


    @PutMapping(path = "/{id}",
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public UserRest updateUser(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody UsersDetailsRequestModel userDetails){

        UserRest returnValue = new UserRest();

        if(userDetails.getFirstName().isEmpty()) throw new NullPointerException("The object is null");

        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails,userDto);

        UserDto updatedUser = userService.updateUser(id, userDto);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(updatedUser,returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/{id}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public OperationStatusModel deleteUser(@PathVariable String id){

        OperationStatusModel returnValue = new OperationStatusModel();
        returnValue.setOperationName(RequestOperationName.DELETE.name());

        userService.deleteUser(id);

        returnValue.setOperationResult(RequestOperationStatus.SUCCESS.name());
        return returnValue;

    }

    @GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public List<UserRest> getUsers(@RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                   @RequestParam(value="limit", defaultValue = "25") int limit){

        List<UserRest> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();

        List<UserDto> users = userService.getUsers(page,limit);

        for(UserDto userDto : users){
            UserRest userModel = new UserRest();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDto, userModel);
            returnValue.add(userModel);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

How can this error be fixed? Any ideas? My project's repo is [here](https://github.com/theo82/restful-webservices). You can clone it in your machine and use postman. Choose a POST request, use this

link: **http://www.localhost:8080/restful-webservices/users** and add in the body the json found at the beginning.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: Please enclose code for `UsersDetailsRequestModel` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs in `UserServiceImpl` class when you try to map `UserDto` to `UserEntity` : `modelMapper.map(user, UserEntity.class);`

**Reason:**

Reason for the error is that you do not have the `getId()` method for `id` in `AddressDTO` so the mapper is trying to map `id` of `AddressEntity` with `addressId` of `AddressDTO` which is a string. Since it is a string it is trying to cast it to `long`.

How to resolve:

Adding a`getId()` to return `id` in `AddressDTO` will fix this:

```
  public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```